# Is it possible to have a local azure environment?

Tags: azure, testing, integration

I am new to azure so maybe there's a better way to do what I am trying to achieve.

I am basically trying to write integration test for a Web Api and I hit a wall as soon as I started using Azure sdk.

Here's how I was doing my integration:

1. I would fire up iis express and launch my web api
2. Issue requests against the api and compare results

So far so good.

But now, I want to use redis cache and this requires the azure environment.

Can this be done or am I approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried installing Redis on your machine? :) Some services can be partially replicated, like Redis. Of course some can't like Search.

Comment: Hi juunas, I have not tried that. I was looking for a self-contained solution.

Comment: No, there is no self contained solution, just components as mentioned - Redis, CosmosDB, Storage emulator, Functions CLI etc.

Comment: Thanks Murray. I did not expect that.